# http://sqlfiddle.com/ - как загрузить 2 таблицы для решения задач

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу загрузить 2 таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
create table #Клиенты (client_id varchar(1), FIO varchar (255) , Region varchar(50), account_num int) 
insert into #Клиенты values  
('A','Иванов','Москва',111), 
('A','Иванов','Москва',222), 
('B','Петров','Иваново',333), 
('C','Сидоров','Москва',444) 
   
create table #Cчета ([Date] date, Summa_USD money, Account_num int) 
insert into #Cчета values 
('2012-01-01',15000,111), 
('2012-02-01',10000,111), 
('2012-02-01',5000,222), 
('2012-03-01',30000,333), 
('2012-04-01',20000,444)
```

Comment: А вы знаете что в  инструкциях БД есть ещё точки с запятой?))

Comment: все равно не дает -пробовал

Comment: А в какой версии есть синтаксис `[Date] date` ?

Comment: так ругается на 1 строку )

Comment: Потомо что это отдельная инструкция........ там чётко написано где конкретно начинается ошибка  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLqON.png

Comment: ругается на первую строку, но это интерфейс так реализован. так что ошибка во второй группе инсертов. перечитывайте документацию. вот в примере тут дата еще и в скобках mysql> INSERT INTO dt (col) VALUES ('2020-01-01 10:10:10'),
    ->     ('2020-01-01 10:10:10+05:30'), ('2020-01-01 10:10:10-08:00');   еще есть вариант STR_TO_DATE

Comment: сначала создайте таблицы. потом закомментируйте их, потом уже вставки.

Comment: ура заработало .СПАСИБО !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь сервисом SQLie.online: https://sqlize.online/s/3i
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]